# Ok, last question regarding search engine on my website

Tags: php, sql, mysql, zend-framework

I have read the intro to the zend manual, and as far as I understand I have to install the framework on my server... And my webhosting provider says they don't support that, so it's not possible...

It must be installed in order for me to use it and implement a search function of my mysql records, right?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all help BTW... very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The Zend Framework itself does not require any specific server side extensions or additional binaries other than PHP 5. You don't need your provider to install it, you should not have any problems just uploading the thing - or even just the Lucene related parts of it - and getting started. The ZF can be used in other PHP applications without it "taking over".

- [Zend Framework Requirements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.html#requirements.extensions)
- [Zend Framework installation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/introduction.installation.html)

Comment: In addition to the `Zend/Search/Lucene` folder, you need `Zend/Exception.php` and that's all.  I just tried running the unit tests after moving aside all the rest of the ZF library files.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can simply use the MySQL [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator to perform a basic search (e.g. title contains "stackoverflow", etc...), or more preferably use the MyISAM storage engine that has fulltext search capabilities.

See the manual for more information about fulltext index and searches : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

But AFAIK, nothing prevents you from uploading the Zend Framework yourself, and use it as usual. The only thing is that you may not be able to write files out of your apache directory (which is required for a standard zend framework folder structure), so check this article on [how to set ZF up on a shared hosting](http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html).

Comment: +1 but it's not strictly necessary required to locate ZF library files outside your htdocs -- it's just a really good idea.

Comment: Also be aware that using `LIKE` predicates can be *thousands* of times slower than using a full-text search engine like Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you dont need to install the entire framework, just the tedpendencies of `Zend_Search_Lucene`. But all you have to do to install is upload the files and make some include path adjustments, then require the nessecary files.